# Visual Studio error in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I am currently reading through the Tony Royce C programming book and I am doing the exercises using Microsoft Visual studio 2015. I have code for one of them.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main();

    char student_name[11];
    int mathsmark = 0;
    int englishmark = 0;
    int computingmark = 0;
    int averagemark = 0;

    printf_s("Please key in your name:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", student_name);

    printf_s("Please key in your English Mark:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", englishmark);

    printf_s("Please key in your Maths Mark:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", mathsmark);

    printf_s("Please key in your Computing Mark:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", computingmark);

    averagemark = englishmark + mathsmark + computingmark / 3;

    printf_s(student_name, "Your average mark is %d", averagemark);



    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code however it comes up with this error:

**"Exception thrown at 0x0F830B5C (ucrtbased.dll) in Tonyroycestuff.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00500000.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."**

And if I press continue it comes up with this error:

**"Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Tonyroycestuff.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003)."**

I'm not sure why and I was wondering if someone could help me with this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is always a good idea to the documentation of the functions one uses. Even better if one gets a fault report. You might notice `scanf_s expects extra parameters.

Comment: In Visual Studio you have a debugger, it allows you to "de bug" your code.  Without any further reading of your code in detail, I would say there is something wrong with pointers. Activate debugger and step through your program (one line after the other). I am pretty sure the code listed in your code did not exactly look like this. When you have an integer you pass its pointer with the & operator to the scan function (to pass its pointer).

Comment: For  a start, check your braces (curly brackets) and semi-colons in the posted code.

Comment: Please! We are talking about C. A real language. With a real compiler and debugger. We do not need to look for those errors. The compiler does find curly brace and semicolon errors. It is not a scripting language that just gets executed and then randomly crashes due to such errors.

Comment: Except that the brace error means the OP did not show us his original code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call scanf_s as:

```
    scanf_s("%d", &englishmark);
```

... and similarly for the other int values.